# Rsync with multiple wildcards

Tags: rsync, remote, synchronization

How can I rsync all files of multiple types from a remote server? E.g. I want to rsync all pdf's and png's from a folder on the server.

This raises a syntax error: `rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf, *.png} LOCAL_PATH`

I've also tried:
`rsync --include='*.png' --include='*.pdf' --exclude='*' REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/ LOCAL_PATH` which syncs nothing (same if `exclude` is at the front)

I'm currently resorting to
`rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/*.pdf LOCAL_PATH; rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/*.png LOCAL_PATH` but would like to do this in one command.

Comment: Are those variables: `REMOTE_SERVER`, `REMOTE_PATH`, etc? If so, shouldn't they be used as `$REMOTE_SERVER`, `$REMOTE_PATH`, etc?

Comment: Not literally. They are just stand-ins for the purpose of this conversation.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
rsync -av --include='*.pdf' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/ LOCAL_PATH
```

And if you are using a nested directory structure you can use:

```
rsync -av --include='*/' --include='*.pdf' --include='*.png' --exclude='*' REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/ LOCAL_PATH
```

I have used exlude and include to include the relevant file formats and exlude all the other formats

Hope that helps

Answer (score 0):

Let's look at what's happening. I'm going to assume you're using `bash` or some other shell that understands brace expansion

> ```
> rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf, *.png} LOCAL_PATH
> ```

If you prefix this with `echo` you'll see that the brace is not expanded:

```
echo rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf, *.png} LOCAL_PATH
rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf, *.png} LOCAL_PATH
```

and `rsync` sees these three arguments: `REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf,`, `*.png}` and `LOCAL_PATH`.

The initial problem is that you've got a space inside the braces, breaking their construction. This is more correct:

```
echo rsync REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf,*.png} LOCAL_PATH
```

and now `rsync` sees these three arguments: `REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/*.pdf`,  `REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/*.png` `LOCAL_PATH`

This would copy all PDF and PNG files from the specified remote directory to the local destination. However, it's not optimised because you've omitted to have `rsync` include file modification times (`--times`, or `-t`).

```
rsync --times REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH/{*.pdf,*.png} LOCAL_PATH
```

If you want to copy all PDF and PNG files from the directory tree rooted from `REMOTE_PATH` you need a different approach entirely:

```
rsync --recursive --times --include '*.pdf' --include '*.png' --include '**/' --exclude '*' --prune‐empty‐dirs REMOTE_SERVER:REMOTE_PATH LOCAL_PATH
```